# Which two tenses should be used with each other?

Tags: tense, questions

I'm having trouble figuring out what tenses to use in a question with two verbs. For instance:

> - Have you cleaned the mess you made?
> - Have you cleaned the mess you have made?
> - Have you cleaned the mess you had made?
> - Did you clean the mess you made?
> - Did you clean the mess you have made?

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: One test that might often be helpful: look at the corresponding declarative clause version and see how it sounds to you. E.g. *"Tom has cleaned up the mess (that) he made"*, for your 1st example. *"Tom has cleaned up the mess (that) he has made"*, for your 2nd example. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick with **you made** because at the time of the question (cleaning time) I imagine the mess was already made, so it is completely in the past. So simple past is fine.

So either of these is OK; some other context would be needed to decide between them.

> Have you cleaned *up* the mess you made?
>   Did you clean *up* the mess you made?

In this context, the phrase [***clean up***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clean+up) is more appropriate.